# Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.ConcurrencyException: Transaction operation attempted on : MoreThan127

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I am using RavenDb hosted in IIS and I have 6 Endpoints including one Saga Endpoint. When I am trying to run Saga and sending commands then I am not able to send the command getting below error:

> `NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver Failed to process
>   message Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.ConcurrencyException:
>   Transaction operation attempted on :
>   MoreThan127/4bba5011-95ee-3093-d78d-11256eeba0fe/12ba382d-a0c
>   c-0166-4519-495075f82fea using a non current etag    at
>
> Raven.Client.Connection.Async.AsyncServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass1d3.<b__1d1>d__1d6.MoveNext()
>   in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven
>   .Client.Lightweight\Connection\Async\AsyncServerClient.cs:line 1430
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>
> Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformerBase`1.d__27`1.MoveNext()
>   in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight
>   \Connection\ReplicationInformerBase.cs:line 422
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>
> Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformerBase`1.d__17`1.MoveNext()
>   in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.L
>   ightweight\Connection\ReplicationInformerBase.cs:line 314
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>
> Raven.Client.Connection.Async.AsyncServerClient.d__28e`1.MoveNext()
>   in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightwe
>   ight\Connection\Async\AsyncServerClient.cs:line 2238
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>
> Raven.Client.Extensions.TaskExtensions2.ResultUnwrap[T](Task`1 task)
>   in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Extensions\TaskExt
>   ensions2.cs:line 59    at
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Batch(IEnumerable`1 commandDatas)
>   in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Serve
>   rClient.cs:line 304    at
>
> Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.SaveChanges() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentSession.cs:line
>   71 4    at
>   NServiceBus.RavenDB.SessionManagement.OpenSessionBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\c4d62ce02b983878\sr
>   c\NServiceBus.RavenDB\SessionManagement\OpenSessionBehavior.cs:line 22
>   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>
> NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95    at
>   NServiceBus.SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServi
>   ceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.cs:line
>   17    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95    at
>   NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context,
>   Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicas
>   t\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line 47    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95    at
>   NServiceBus.InvokeSagaNotFoundBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context,
>   Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\
>   Unicast\Behaviors\InvokeSagaNotFoundBehavior.cs:line 19    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95    at
>   NServiceBus.ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServic
>   eBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line
>   24    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95    at
>   NServiceBus.ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.C
>   ore\Unicast\Messages\ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line 24    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95    at
>   NServiceBus.CallbackInvocationBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context,
>   Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\
>   Unicast\Behaviors\CallbackInvocationBehavior.cs:line 23    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95    at
>   NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceB
>   us.Core\Unicast\Messages\DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line 48
>   at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   109
>
> at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorC
>   hain.cs:line 95

Any idea what could be the solution!

Comment: Does this happen under load or does it happen all the time?

Comment: Maybe this is obvious but it looks like two things are trying to update the same document at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution, This issue was happening because I was not finding the exact saga to update the sagadata instance. Somehow, it was grabbing some other instance of saga and trying to update it which doesnot belong to the correct resourcemanagerid of ravendb and it was throwing exception.

When I resolved the saga correctly then it got resolved.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post, but I was facing the same error recently and this post is the one that you'd find first when you google.

This problem occurred after I deleted the Raven Resource in Raven Studio while keeping the files on disk. I had to delete the resource again with the Delete option: "Delete everything" on.

SideNote: This was in my development environment, I'd probably would be more careful in a production environment.